# Laravel SendingI form data through error email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the error handler page to send an email to tech support whenever a 500 error is hit with the error.
Is there a way to pass through the current form requested data so I can get more information?

```
if ($e instanceof \Exception) {
   // emails.exception is the template of your email
    // it will have access to the $error that we are passing below
Mail::send('emails.error',['error' => $e->getMessage()], function($message {
$message->to('devorah@cucumber.com')->subject('Laravel Error');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access all request data from the `Request` facade like so:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all();
```